# MATLAB cannot round non-zero entries to a specific decimal place

Tags: matlab, rounding

What does the following statement mean?

> *"MATLAB cannot round non-zero entries to specific decimal place, because of that there will always be leftovers around `1e-16` for doubles (double precision variables) and `1e-12` for singles."*
>
> ***EXAMPLE:***
>
> *`time(3001)=0` and `find(time==0)=3001`
>
>   but `time(3000)=-1e4` and `find(time==-1e4) = []`
>
>   because `time(3000) + 1e-4 = -2.11e-16` and `single(time(3000)) + 1e-4 = 2.53e-12`*.

Comment: I think the note message is pretty clear and they even provide a example!

Comment: What does it mean by leftovers?

Comment: Read this to know how computer store float: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format .

Comment: For example, compute `0.0000001 + 0.0000000001` you will get `1.0009999999999999e-07` not ``0.0000001001`

Comment: So this does not only apply to Matlab?

Comment: @MussleTesfay every single programming language. It all deals with how the CPU deals with floating point numbers as they're not infinite precision. I also recommend reading the perils of floating point for a good picture too: http://www.lahey.com/float.htm

Comment: Very helpful indeed. Thank you so much!